# Add custom item to right click menu when user selects text

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to add a custom menu item to the menu that appears when a user selects some text and right clicks. I searched a lot but did not get any answer. Maybe I did not put in the right keyword.

1. Is it possible to do this?
2. If this is possible, I want to do this for all applications in windows whenever the user selects text. Is there a universal way to do it or will have to write code specific to the application?

I am using C#.

Comment: You could add a global hook to handle right mouse clicks and pop up your own ContextMenu... But if I installed your app and it had this functionality I'd probably have to kill you. :)

Comment: glace: There can be also the unforeseen consequences when some application has a custom handling of right mouse click. For example games, modeling software, etc. I'm not sure if "right click with intention of showing context menu" is even detectable.

Comment: Hence, why I said I'd have to kill him. Someone with more knowledge of the Windows subsystem would have to chime in, cause I'm not really sure how game devs make sure that their input is accepted first and not propagated to other processes.

Comment: Depends on what kind of game. I personally use global hooks for example. There's also DirectInput for DirectX based games. I guess the gamers wouldn't be happy to try to throw a grenade, only to find out unlimit's context menu has just opened. As well as 3D modeler trying to rotate a view. But it could really win a prize for the most annoying software this year.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that universally in all windows apps. But it is certainly possible to do in your own app using a popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried a way to add an item to the standard ContextMenu and failed.  From my point of view, the only solution is to set the TextBox's ContextMenuStrip property to an instance of the ContextMenuStrip class and implement both standard and your custom menu items.  It is easy to mimic standard operation, since the TextBox class provides all required methods:  Cut, Copy, Paste, SelectAll.

Answer (score 0):

The universal way is basically writing a "custom shell extension". 
There is an article on CodeProject about how to do this.

[image: Custom Shell Extension]

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang

The other way to do this is to build this into your application. For example you might have a text editor and you'll want to highlight a word and get a definition for that word. To do this you'll need to implement a context menu. 
The VERY BASIC concept is detailed over on CodeReview.StackExchange.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3983/c-programatically-creating-context-menu