# insert an item in the menu context of any text editor (on windows)

Tags: windows, action, contextmenu, text-editor, launch

I want to simplify a process by right-clicking in a text editor. this item launchs a *.bat file.
I have searched in the registry editor. I know how create the keys, but I know where create them to add this action after the famous "cut, copy, paste, ..."

by advance thank you.

[image]

Comment: Asked many times already, some quick searches: [Can I add a custom paste option to the windows text editing context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17370415/), [Can I edit the context menu of a text field (not Explorer context menu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39827324), [Add custom item to right click menu when user selects text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14366708).

Comment: thank you. I hope this helps. thank you raymond.

Answer (score 1):

CudaText editor (free) has this feature via Configure Menu plugin. You run the plugin, create the menu JSON file, then edit this file, to add any command.

How to add command for Bat file? Via plugin External Tools. Add there command to call bat file.